# Changing field type of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, mergeshapes, integer

I have two polygon shapefiles that I need to merge. I applied 'Merge vector layers' tool from Data management in QGIS 3.16, but it took too long to process and I realized a message indicating that one shp has `integer` field type and the other `integer64`.

Assuming this is the problem why the process could not be completed, how can I change the data type of one of these layers? And which one should it be?

Comment: I usually get that error when merging two layers that have fields with the same name but different data types. Try renaming one of them or use **Refactor fields** to change type to the same. I dont think the type you choose will matter, I would go with **int**

Comment: Integer fits also into integer64 but the largest numbers that integer64 support do not fit into integer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried Refactor fields and changed the integer64 data type to integer32 and the Merge process completed successfully.